# Counting strings in files and putting the value in different places using c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to count some strings in files in a given location and then put those values in some nodes.
I've tried the below code

```
var workingPath=@"D:\Test\MyFiles";
            var files = new List<string>();
            if (Directory.Exists(workingPath))
            {
                foreach (var f in Directory.GetDirectories(workingPath, "xml",
                                                           SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(f, "*.xml"));
                }
            }

            foreach (var file in files) {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                int fig_count = Regex.Matches(text, @"fig id=""fig").Count;
                int tab_count = Regex.Matches(text, @"table-wrap id=""table").Count;
                int eq_count = Regex.Matches(text, @"disp-formula id=""deqn").Count;
                File.WriteAllText(file,Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(file), @"<fig-count count=""\d+""/>",@"<fig-count count="""+fig_count+@"""/>"));
                File.WriteAllText(file,Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(file), @"<table-count count=""\d+""/>",@"<table-count count="""+tab_count+@"""/>"));
                File.WriteAllText(file,Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(file), @"<eq-count count=""\d+""/>",@"<eq-count count="""+eq_count+@"""/>"));
            }
```

The code works but it is a bit redundant. Can anyone tell me how to make it less redundant?

Comment: Second the suggestion for CodeReview. But also, the optimisation would depend on how big your files are, and how many matches you expect to find. Definitely start with the suggestions below of writing only once. If you have a bunch of small files, then consider looking into Parallel.ForEach. If you have massive files, and only one or two matches, then you'll need to optimise the code a bit more

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a site for specific questions, not code reviews

Answer (score 3):

I suggest extracting a TextUpdate method and read & write the file only once:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
    text = UpdateText(text, "fig", Regex.Matches(text, @"fig id=""fig").Count);
    text = UpdateText(text, "table", Regex.Matches(text, @"table-wrap id=""table").Count);
    text = UpdateText(text, "eq", Regex.Matches(text, @"disp-formula id=""deqn").Count);
    File.WriteAllText(file, text);
}

private static string UpdateText(string text, string type, int count)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, "<" + type + @"-count count=""\d+""/>", "<" + type + @"-count count=""" + count + @"""/>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below only reads and writes file once :

```
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            int fig_count = Regex.Matches(text, @"fig id=""fig").Count;
            int tab_count = Regex.Matches(text, @"table-wrap id=""table").Count;
            int eq_count = Regex.Matches(text, @"disp-formula id=""deqn").Count;
            text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<fig-count count=""\d+""/>", @"<fig-count count=""" + fig_count + @"""/>");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<table-count count=""\d+""/>", @"<table-count count=""" + tab_count + @"""/>");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<eq-count count=""\d+""/>", @"<eq-count count=""" + eq_count + @"""/>");
            File.WriteAllText(file, text);
```